# Jquery Slider, cant get it to work

Tags: jquery, slider

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">@import url(/css/slider.css);</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

<style type="text/css">
.ui-slider-handle {
border:1px solid silver;
height:10px;width:10px;
background-color:black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all').slider( { minValue: 0%, maxValue: 100%, animate: true} );
</script>
<div id="example1" class="cropper-slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-    widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-    default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Script doesn't to control the slider bar at all. I'm completely clueless as to what I'm doing wrong here. Can I get some advice as to what I need to do in order to get this slider range bar to work?

Comment: So your trying to bind on elements that don't exist yet.  Your logic needs to be after your html declarations or inside a document ready.  You may also have some issue with your selector.  '.class1.class2' is a logical AND, '.class1 .class2' is a logical nesting

Comment: I'm trying to make a slider range bar for a image cropper. I've never used Jquery APIs really before and I'm confused how I go about an making a simple slider to function. Example: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a2/#docs/forms/forms-slider.html Looks a lot like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually very simple. In your code, you try to modify the parameters `minValue` and `maxValue`.

By taking a look at the jQuery API, these parameters don't exist. They are in fact, `min` and `max`. However, you also try to set it as a percentage of the screen. This doesn't work either, as the parameter is a number, not a percentage.

I have devised a simple solution to what I think you are trying to accomplish. Mind that I changed the identifier from `'.ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all'` to `#example1`

**HTML/jQuery/CSS:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">@import url(/css/slider.css);</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css">
.ui-slider-handle {
border:1px solid silver;
height:10px;width:10px;
background-color:black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example1" class="cropper-slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-    widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-    default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a></div>
<script>$("#example1").slider( { animate:true, max:$("#example1").width(), min:0 } );</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0evLwncn/

P.S. I'd recommend organizing your code a bit better, and looking at the API next time.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks I copied and pasted the script that you gave me and it work exactly the way I want it to. I'll study it and try and implement it into my site. Thanks!

Comment: Last question is will I be able to use this with the crop master API?

Comment: @JonW Sorry, I don't know anything about the crop master API, you will have to test that out yourself. I assume it will work, however.